# are there any good tutorials about installing cloudera manager on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, hadoop

I followed the [cloudera manager installation guide](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/FREE41DOC/Cloudera+Manager+Free+Edition+Installation+Guide) to setup cloudera manager on a cluster of vmware virtual machines running ubuntu desktop 12.04, but I found it a little complicated since I'am new to both ubuntu an Hadoop worlds.
so are there any good tutorials about installing cloudera manager on a cluster of ubuntu 12.04 instances?

Comment: Do you read french by any chance? If not the link you suggest is the easiest and most complete guide you can have. You just need to go through it slowly and while you're doing so pick up the part you need.